# Is There any way to know when all element that uses angular directives get compiled?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

My question is very simples... Is There any way to know when all elements that uses angular directives get compiled?

Ex, i have this html:

```
<ul data-ng-controller="DemoController">
  <li data-ng-repeat="info in data" some-directive-here>{{info.detail}}</li>
</ul>
```

And this script:

```
app.controller('DemoController', function ($scope) {
  $scope.data = [{detail: 'test1'}, {detail: 'test2'}, {detail: 'test3'}];
});
```

And i want to know two things, is there any way to know when angular compiles all directives above(i mean, all directives from document)? And is there any way to know when all "some-directive-here" get compiled?

Comment: The question is why do you want to to do that? :) It smells funny... What I mean is that you *may* be trying to do something that can be accomplished in an easier and more robust way.

Comment: i need to know when angular compiles all directives from document, or at least, to know when all "some-directive-here" from example of my code get compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can be sure everything is finished and compiled by watching this event:

```
$scope.$watch('$viewContentLoaded', function()
        {
            console.log("Emitted every time the ngView content is reloaded.")
        });
```

And if you want to know if one specific directive finished all its operation. You need to implement it in such a way that it holds the length of items it's going to deal with and stores it.

Once the operation at the end of the directive is for the last index you can emit your own custom event which you can listen for.

I trust you can imagine the implementation yourself based on your some-directive-here code.

Comment: i´ve already solved my problem, but i didn't know about "$viewContentLoaded", thanks! and about the length to deal with finished directives i thought about that too, but i didn't like it.